# Leaflet rendering TileMill tiles in the wrong order

Tags: raster, javascript, leaflet, tilemill, browser

I'm stumped, and quite a lot of searching has turned up nothing helpful.

I'm on the first step of what will ultimately be a map with three raster layers and three layers of markers (with controls to toggle between the rasters and their associated data, with popups/tooltips for the data), but I can't get the Tilemill tiles to render properly. (I created the rasters in QGIS, ran them through GDAL to colorize and re-project them, and then put them into TileMill.)

To wit:
[image]
That's in Chrome. This is Safari:
[image]

And here's the code, which looks quite innocuous to me (I've commented out everything but the tiles at this point, so that's all I've included):

```
<html>
<head>
 <title> - Leaflet demo</title>
 <script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
 <style type='text/css'>
 html, body{ width:100%; height: 100%, margin:0; padding:0; }
 #map{ width:700px; height:600px }
 img {margin:0px;padding:0px};
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
//one base layer on map
var map = new L.Map( "map" ).setView([38.173,-94.384],5);
L.tileLayer('http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mtgmediagroup.beef2013/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
 attribution: 'Dani Friedland/MTG Media Group',
 maxZoom: 9
}).addTo(map);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<b>Map</b>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Has anyone ever encountered this problem? If so, how did you overcome it? I'm eager to start into the rest of the process of making this map (by which of course I mean "uncovering the next problem to solve").

*Edited to add:* I tried re-exporting a new MBTiles file, uploading it as new data, and creating a new Mapbox project from that data. No dice. Next step in isolating the issue would be to set up the MBTiles file on a server, skipping Mapbox, but that seems more likely to create problems than to fix them.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You forgot to add Leaflet CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
```

Also there are numerous typos in your code: for example, in `html, body{}` stylesheet line. Do check for them before deploying to production.

Comment: You're absolutely right, and that took care of it! I just _knew_ it was something stupid like that. Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old and has already been solved, but I have another solution for anyone who is presently having this same issue. If you've loaded in your CSS and it is still not displaying the tiles correctly, you need to include `tms: true` in your **TileLayer** options.

An example of my code:

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([0, 0], 3)

L.tileLayer('http://localhost/map/MapData/sat/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        minZoom: 1, maxZoom: 7,
        tms: true,
        attribution: 'World Map'
    }).addTo(mymap);
```

Hope this helps someone else with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

When we do not add css/Style for map, it does not render map as it should looks like.

In react just import leaflet and leaflet.css.

```
> import L from "leaflet"; 
> import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
```

Before writing any code for the map, you need to do the following preparation steps on your page:

**Include Leaflet CSS file in the head section of your document:**

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
   crossorigin=""/>
```

**Include Leaflet JavaScript file after Leaflet’s CSS:**

```
<!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
   crossorigin=""></script>
```

Put a div element with a certain id where you want your map to be:

```
 <div id="mapid"></div>
```

Make sure the map container has a defined height, for example by setting it in CSS:

```
#mapid { height: 180px; }
```